How can I keep the context when using `thiserror` and `anyhow` context
I'm trying to create custom errors for some function:
use anyhow::Context;
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum BufferPoolError {
    #[error("Could not allocate new page as no frame available to evict")]
    NoEvictableFrames,

    // More

    #[error("unknown buffer pool error")]
    Unknown,
}

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors {
    #[error("Tried to split bucket for {0} times")]
    ReachedRetryLimit(usize),

    #[error("buffer pool error")]
    BufferPoolError(#[from] BufferPoolError),

    #[error("unknown extensible hashing split error")]
    Unknown,
}

fn create_new_page_in_buffer_pool() -> Result<(), BufferPoolError> {
    Err(BufferPoolError::NoEvictableFrames)
}

fn unpin_page_from_buffer_pool() -> Result<(), BufferPoolError> {
    Err(BufferPoolError::Unknown)
}

fn split() -> Result<(), ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors> {
    create_new_page_in_buffer_pool()
        .map_err(ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::from)?;

    // ...

    unpin_page_from_buffer_pool()
        .map_err(ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::from)?;

    // ...
    
    Ok(())
}


Which works fine, but I can't add context to the error as it will change the error to anyhow::Error

fn split() -> Result<(), ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors> {
    create_new_page_in_buffer_pool()
        .context("Failed to create new page when trying to split")
        .map_err(ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::from)?;
    
    Ok(())
}
fn split() -> Result<(), ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors> {
    create_new_page_in_buffer_pool()
        .context("Failed to create new page when trying to split")
        .map_err(ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::from)?;

    // ...

    unpin_page_from_buffer_pool()
        .context("Failed to unpin page when trying to split")
        .map_err(ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::from)?;

    // ...
    
    Ok(())
}

which will fail understandably on:
the trait bound `ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors: From<anyhow::Error>` is not satisfied

Rust Playground Link
I thought of doing:
impl From<anyhow::Error> for ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors {
    fn from(error: anyhow::Error) -> Self {
        if let Some(e) = error.downcast_ref::<BufferPoolError>() {
            return ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::from(e.clone());
        }

        ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::Unknown
    }
}

But then I lose the context
I also tried snafu but was unable to make it work

You could create a further error type that represents this specific error, with the desired context as descriptive text?

This sounds like what you really want is for split() to have its own error type, which can just be struct SplitError(ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors);. The "context" then lives purely in the type system and adds no runtime cost.

I don't want to have specific error for split as there is no specific behavior on how to handle that, I want to add context for better debugging in case of a failure

@RazLuvaton That's exactly what a wrapper will give you -- the ability to add context.

Sorry, I do want specific error for split, the split own error type is ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors, how wrapping that would solve the issue?

@RazLuvaton Oh, right. Well, then no context is needed. If that's the error type for that function then the fact that this error occurred already tells you that it happened in this function. What problem are you trying to solve by adding context? Typically context is added by the caller to disambiguate where an error occurred if multiple points in the code can produce the same error type.

split do call multiple functions that all produce BufferPool error, buffer pool error has other error variants, I'll clarify the question

@RazLuvaton Okay, there is a solution for this. Let me draft an answer.

To add context, you need somewhere to store it. When using anyhow, the anyhow::Error type contains this context. This is why the context is lost when you downcast it back to the concrete error type ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors; this type has no place to actually store the context.
To solve this, give it somewhere to store the context.  In this case, the context can be an enum that contains a list of the possible points of failure.
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum BufferPoolErrorSource {
    CreateNewPage,
    UnpinPage,
}

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors {
    #[error("Tried to split bucket for {0} times")]
    ReachedRetryLimit(usize),

    #[error("buffer pool error during {1:?}")]
    BufferPoolError(BufferPoolError, BufferPoolErrorSource),

    #[error("unknown extensible hashing split error")]
    Unknown,
}

Then you can provide this context when creating the BufferPoolError variant:
fn split() -> Result<(), ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors> {
    create_new_page_in_buffer_pool().map_err(|e| {
        ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::BufferPoolError(e, BufferPoolErrorSource::CreateNewPage)
    })?;

    // ...

    unpin_page_from_buffer_pool().map_err(|e| {
        ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::BufferPoolError(e, BufferPoolErrorSource::UnpinPage)
    })?;

    // ...

    Ok(())
}


Is this the standard way to do it? it seems like a lot of boilerplate in the error mapping

@RazLuvaton It seems pretty idiomatic to me. You could make the boilerplate a bit shorter with a method on BufferPoolErrorSource, but if you want to convey where an error happened, you need some piece of data to do that.

@RazLuvaton You can trim some of the boilerplate by adding use ExtendibleHashTableSplitErrors::*; use BufferPoolErrorSource::*; inside of source() as well, and then you can .map_err(|e| BufferPoolError(e, CreateNewPage)) for example.

I ended up doing some wrapper around anyhow that is strictly typed on specific errors

@RazLuvaton That might be the worst possible way to do this.

Why is that? If it get the job done while solving my problem

@RazLuvaton I'm not saying it doesn't work, just that it's a horribly inefficient way to do this, as well as not idiomatic. anyhow::Error stores a bunch of info on the heap. You're causing a bunch of extra allocations for something you can store inline (per my answer) plus you're inverting the error layers by wrapping an anyhow::Error in another error type. I'd suggest either going all-in on anyhow::Error and using its facilities such as downcasting, or using the approach in my answer, which has none of the overhead of anyhow.
